# Get width and height of image on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to get the width and height of the image on click. Below is my code:

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function(){
 alert("Image clicked, width is __px and height is __px");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```

I would like the dimensions of the image and not the `width="100" height="100"` tag I have written in `img attr`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass an argument to the callback function and then access the `target` of the event and its `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties, like so:

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-img").click(function(e){
 alert("Image clicked, width is "+e.target.naturalWidth+"px and height is "+e.target.naturalHeight+"px");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img class="sim-row-edit-img" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png" width="100" height="100">
```